# Store ALL state in Redux and group/nest state by page/view following the folder structure

Tags: redux, react-redux

As a newcomer to Redux, one of the hardest parts of learning Redux is deciding what goes in Redux and what stays as local state. I've read most of the documentation, but still I think it's quite hard to decide.

In my case, I ended up putting all state into Redux, since I prioritized fine grained control: both time-travelling and the ability to preload the entire application state from configuration files was of high priority. Also you get the bonus of being able to inspect all state in your application in 1 place with redux dev tools, which is nice.

I liked the idea proposed here: https://medium.com/@alexmngn/how-to-use-redux-on-highly-scalable-javascript-applications-4e4b8cb5ef38 which relies heavily on reducer composition, so I implemented it like this.

The idea being that; nesting, storing and encapsulating components and state where it is used, and also so the state reflects the folder structure of your application. This way, your project and state is so well structured, it's actually almost just as easy to put the state in Redux than using local state - and definitely seems to be worth the little additional LOC.

It seems to work pretty well, however I must say I wonder why so few people seem to recommend doing it that way.

In a redux application where you have a lot of different pages/routes with different state on each, would it then be considered a valid approach to group state by page/route, or is this some kind of anti pattern?

```
{
  reduxRoute: { /* globally available */ }
  session: { /* globally available */ }
  data: { /* globally available */ }
  scenes: {
    Page1: {
      state1: { /* ui state specifically for this view/page */ }
      state2: { /* ui state specifically for this view/page */ }
      data: { /* data state specifically for this view/page */ }
    },
    Page2: {
      state3: { /* ui state specifically for this view/page */ }
      state4: { /* ui state specifically for this view/page */ }
      otherData: { /* data state specifically for this view/page */ }
    }
  }
}
```

Right now the app is working, but I do not intend to keep Page1 state when navigating to Page2 - I only want to represent it nicely, when you're on a given page/view/scene.

So I was thinking about triggering a RESET_PAGE1_STATE action in the componentDidUnmount lifecycle function of Page1 (for all pages), to fix this.

The reason for this question is that you typically hear people recommend storing stuff at the top level, but with certain state being only relevant for certain pages/views/scenes, I'd like to structure it a bit more and avoid having useless null valies for state3 and state4 in my root state, when being on Page1 - therefore the grouping.

Some people will probably say that if you have this kind of problem, you're probably doing it wrong. If some state is only relevant for a single page/view/scene some would probably say it belongs in local state - but for the additional control I mentioned (time travelling and being able to preload the entire app from configuration files) - surely it is necessary to keep it all in redux right?

Hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that keeping irrelevent for the current page stuff is a problem. May be a problem for performance reasons say you have thousands of records but otherwise I think is fine. Especially if you want to support a user journey like going to previous page.

As for where the state should stay: I tend to put UI related data in the components while logic related in Redux's store. For example flags that control visibility of something stay in the component while the current step of a questionnaire goes to the application state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Following the structure he describes in the article I linked to, putting ALL state in Redux is not THAT much harder than simply storing some of it in local state. I'm kinda lost on why people always seem to recommend local state for ui state instead of seperating state by domains - global, page1, page2 etc... you DO get the advantage of being able inspect your whole state in dev tools, time travelling, easier preloading of initial state + most importantly... consistency! This guy seems to agree: https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/redux-and-global-state-vs-local-state/4187/15